# Why can I only sometimes import from other directories?

Tags: python, anaconda

I am working on a project that involves remotely running code on compute clusters. My project directory structure is as follows:

```
Project
├── analysis
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── B.py
├── data
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── A.py
├── __init__.py
```

Inside **B.py** I have a print statement:

```
print("foo")
```

Inside **A.py** I have:

```
from analysis import B
```

When I run **A.py** on my local machine everything runs smoothly and I see the print statement. When I upload the project to the remote cluster and run it there I get a `ModuleNotFoundError`.

My question is:
**what's the specific difference between the python environment/installation on my local machine and that on the remote cluster that is causing this behaviour?** From looking at other answers I understand that there are ways one could work around this by, for example, importing `sys` at the start of my code but I would prefer to actually understand why this is happening under-the-hood.

My local machine is running a python 3.8 in a venv and the remote cluster is running a python 3.10 in a conda environment.

Using `from ..analysis import B` I get `ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package`.

Comment: I've tried editing the $PYTHONPATH evironment variable on the cluster but this doesn't seem to have an effect.

Comment: Does `from ..analysis import B` work in one or both places? Odds are the difference is related to your working directory. The correct solution is to never rely on the implicit packaginess of the working directory (it's not always there, and it can change in different environments) and make a proper installable package, then use relative imports from within the package (so instead of `python3 path/to/packname/subpackage/script.py`, install the package properly and then run `python3 -m packname.subpackage.script` (so it looks up the thing to run as a package), and the relative imports just work.

Comment: @S.Dauncey Please [edit] to add details instead of using comments

Answer (score 0):

**SOLUTION**

I solved this by installing my code as a package (thanks to @ShadowRanger). To do this I navigated to my project folder, installed conda-build with

`conda install conda-build`

and ran

`conda develop .`